# I have a problem in my training model in tensor shaping, I am working on Arabart pretrained model in text summarization and I am trying to improve it

Tags: tensorflow, data-science, huggingface-transformers

```
import json
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoConfig
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torch
import numpy as np
import torch.nn.functional as F

# Specify the device (CPU or GPU)
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Load and preprocess the labeled dataset
def load_labeled_dataset(file_path):
    dataset = []
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for line in file:
            data = json.loads(line)
            example_id = data['example_id']
            paragraph = data['paragraph']
            summary = data['summary']
            dataset.append((example_id, paragraph, summary))
    return dataset

# Custom dataset class
class LabeledDataset(Dataset):
    def _init_(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('moussaKam/AraBART')

    def _len_(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def _getitem_(self, index):
        example_id, paragraph, summary = self.data[index]
        inputs = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(paragraph, truncation=True, padding='max_length', max_length=512,
                                            return_tensors='pt')
        labels = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(summary, truncation=True, padding='max_length', max_length=110,
                                            return_tensors='pt')
        return {
            'input_ids': inputs['input_ids'].squeeze(),
            'attention_mask': inputs['attention_mask'].squeeze(),
            'labels': labels['input_ids'].squeeze()
        }

# Load and preprocess the labeled dataset
labeled_dataset = load_labeled_dataset('/content/labeled_validation_dataset.jsonl')

# Create an instance of the labeled dataset
dataset = LabeledDataset(labeled_dataset)

# Configure the model
model_config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained('moussaKam/AraBART')
model_config.num_labels = 2  # Binary classification for sequence-to-sequence model

# Create the model
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained('moussaKam/AraBART', config=model_config)

# Move the model to the device
model.to(device)

# Define training parameters
batch_size = 8
num_epochs = 12
learning_rate = 1e-5

# Create a data loader for training
data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# Define the optimizer and loss function
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Inverse Normalized KL Divergence function
def inverse_normalized_kl_divergence(reference_logits, generated_logits):
    reference_probs = torch.softmax(reference_logits.float(), dim=-1)

    # Truncate or pad the generated logits to match the size of the reference logits
    sequence_length_diff = reference_logits.size(1) - generated_logits.size(1)
    if sequence_length_diff > 0:
        generated_logits = F.pad(generated_logits, (0, sequence_length_diff))
    elif sequence_length_diff < 0:
        reference_logits = F.pad(reference_logits, (0, -sequence_length_diff))

    generated_probs = torch.softmax(generated_logits.float(), dim=-1)

    print("Reference Probs Shape:", reference_probs.shape)
    print("Generated Probs Shape:", generated_probs.shape)

    kl_div = torch.sum(reference_probs * torch.log(reference_probs / (generated_probs + 1e-10)), dim=(-1, -2))
    inverse_kl_div = 1 / (1 + kl_div)
    metric = torch.mean(inverse_kl_div)
    return metric




# Training loop
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    total_metric = 0.0
    num_batches = 0

    for batch in data_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
        attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
        labels = batch['labels'].to(device)

        outputs = model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)
        loss = outputs.loss
        logits = outputs.logits

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # Calculate Inverse Normalized KL Divergence metric for the batch
        metric = inverse_normalized_kl_divergence(reference_logits=labels, generated_logits=logits)
        total_metric += metric.item()
        num_batches += 1

    # Calculate average metric for the epoch
    average_metric = total_metric / num_batches

    # Print the average metric for the epoch
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs} | Average Inverse Normalized KL Divergence: {average_metric:.4f}")

# Save the trained model
model.save_pretrained('trained_model')
```

Every time I am trying to run this training model I got this error

Reference Probs Shape: torch.Size([8, 110])
Generated Probs Shape: torch.Size([8, 110, 50002])

---

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

in <cell line: 96>()
113
114         # Calculate Inverse Normalized KL Divergence metric for the batch
--> 115         metric = inverse_normalized_kl_divergence(reference_logits=labels, generated_logits=logits)
116         total_metric += metric.item()
117         num_batches += 1

in inverse_normalized_kl_divergence(reference_logits, generated_logits)
85     print("Generated Probs Shape:", generated_probs.shape)
86
---> 87     kl_div = torch.sum(reference_probs * torch.log(reference_probs / (generated_probs + 1e-10)), dim=(-1, -2))
88     inverse_kl_div = 1 / (1 + kl_div)
89     metric = torch.mean(inverse_kl_div)

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (110) must match the size of tensor b (50002) at non-singleton dimension 2

[image]

I am working with small labeled dataset on the model
I am working on text summarization problem using arabart pretrained model, and I am trying to improve inverse normalized kl score in the model training